# Identity INT column reached to max limit in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and one of the table in production with column `INT` `identity(1,1)` with `primary key clustered` reached to its maximum limit. 
Can somebody please help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: Use a bigint instead. Change the column type to bigint

Comment: Change the column to a `bigint`. If it's a foreign key, you could be in for a world of hurt though, I'm afraid. This is why many start their `IDENTITY` seed at -2,147,483,648; as the actual value is meaningless to anything but the RDBMS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Yes, was thinking for the same but when we perform alter on table from INT to BIGINT will that going to have any changes in the column values are it is going to be the same ?

Comment: @Larnu - Nope there is no FK key on that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try alter the table column

```
ALTER TABLE OneTable ALTER COLUMN ID bigint
```

In case of primary key or FK dependency, it would fail with below error:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The object ‘PK_OneTable’ is
>   dependent on column ‘ID’. Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1 ALTER
>   TABLE ALTER COLUMN ID failed because one or more objects access this
>   column.

Solution 1

1. Create a new bigint column in the table
2. Update that new column with the values from the int column
3. Delete the int column
4. Rename the bigint column

Comment: will this command going to execute when there is a primary key clustered on it ?

Comment: If it isn't in a Foreign Key, yes @VikrantMore . It will, however, need to completely rewrite the entire tables pages.

Comment: You mean rebuild indexes on non-clustered indexes ?

Comment: No, I mean rewrite the pages. `bigint` is double the size of an `int`, so the all the pages are going to need to be rewritten if it's your `CLUSTERED INDEX`; so that the new size of `ID` fits.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the explanation on rewrite the pages

Comment: If there is no FK dependencies in that case can i perform below things,
1. Drop PK Constraint 
2. Alter Identity column from INT to BIGINT
3. Re-Create dropped PK constraint
Will this be going to work on same column instead?

Comment: @VigneshKumarA - i am sorry i mean to say its PK CLUSTERED

Comment: @VigneshKumarA - Altering existing column from INT to BIGINT is fine or do we need to create same table as it is with ID column to BIGINT and move data into this table and indexes and drop existing table with having ID column with data type INT and then rename permanent temp created with BIGINT column ?

Comment: If existing columns doesn't have any foreign key relationship means, then simple alter the existing ID column from int to bigint